# Post Batch Image on parse using iOS application.(http://www.parse.com)

Tags: parse-platform, image-uploading

How can i upload multiple image simultaneously to parse server(www.parse.com) upload using parse api .Currently i am able to upload single image at a time.Our requirement is to upload multiple image in single request.

Comment: Is it not a valid question?  Why you guys down voted?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I strongly suggest you show what you have tried and what issues you want help with. Currently your question is to vague.

Comment: Timothy ,I have corrected my question ,i guess now it is clear enough to you genious guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse only supports single file uploads per request, though you can do multi-threaded code and upload using multiple requests.

Comment: @ Timothy :Thanks for your answer. :)